# ASP.Net Core 2.2 SignInManager 'No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Application'

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-identity

I have the following configurations in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
    o.LoginPath = Routes.Urls.AdminAccountLogin;
    o.AccessDeniedPath = Routes.Urls.AdminAccountAccessdenied;
}).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions => {});
```

The application throws the following exception when the controller Login action calls `SignInManger.PasswordSignInAsync`:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Application'. The registered sign-in schemes are: Cookies. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Identity.Application",...)?'

Where does the `Identity.Application` come from?

Comment: In most cases, you could simply treat `SignInManger.PasswordSignInAsync` as a method that eventually invokes `await Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,userPrincipal,authenticationProperties);` That's where the `Identity.Application` comes. In short, you didn't add identity authentication scheme, so the ASP.NET Core doesn't knows it.

Comment: I'm running into the same error.  How exactly do you add the identity authentication scheme in startup.cs for a .NET Core 3 application?

Answer (score 4):

Short (and not as helpful) Answer:

Specifically it comes from the `microsoft.aspnetcore.identity` package in the class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`

Long Answer, with the whole breakdown:

You need to add Identity - That scheme is stood up and connected to authentication in the `AddIdentity` extension method

The extension method is in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions`

```cs
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction) where TUser: class where TRole: class
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(delegate (AuthenticationOptions options) {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            }).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions o) {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                CookieAuthenticationEvents events1 = new CookieAuthenticationEvents();
                events1.OnValidatePrincipal = new Func<CookieValidatePrincipalContext, Task>(SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync);
                o.Events = events1;
            }).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions o) {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double) 5.0);
            }).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions o) {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
                CookieAuthenticationEvents events1 = new CookieAuthenticationEvents();
                events1.OnValidatePrincipal = new Func<CookieValidatePrincipalContext, Task>(SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>);
                o.Events = events1;
            }).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions o) {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double) 5.0);
            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>>();
            if (setupAction != null)
            {
                services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(setupAction);
            }
            return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
        }
```

If you follow this `AddCookie` call

```cs
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions o) {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                CookieAuthenticationEvents events1 = new CookieAuthenticationEvents();
                events1.OnValidatePrincipal = new Func<CookieValidatePrincipalContext, Task>(SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync);
                o.Events = events1;
```

it eventually configures `AuthenticationOptions` with the "Identity.Application" scheme and a `CookieAuthenticationHandler`

When you call `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`:

- `SignInManager` checks the username/password in the database (and does two factor flow if enabled), then if good
- creates the `ClaimsPrincipal` and sends it to `HttpContext.SignInAsync` (an extension method) with the identity application scheme, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/30eec7d2ae99ad86cfd9fca8759bac0214de7b12/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L195)
- Which gets the `IAuthenticationService` (added to DI by `AddAuthentication`), see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L143)
- In `AuthenticationService`, it uses a chain of objects

  - `IAuthenticationHandlerProvider` => `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` => the previously configured `AuthenticationOptions` to construct an `AuthenticationScheme` which serves up the `IAuthenticationHandler` in this  case `CookieAuthenticationHandler`. see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/814a37548b6adae2f846eae3144e8f37c1388520/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationService.cs#L194) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/814a37548b6adae2f846eae3144e8f37c1388520/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationHandlerProvider.cs#L47) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/bc7092a32b1943c7f17439e419d3f66cd94ce9bd/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core/AuthenticationSchemeProvider.cs#L123)
  - `CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignInAsync` creates, encrypts and adds the cookie.

Now the cookie is there, so the next request (often a redirect after login) in the `AuthenticationMiddleware`, the `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync` method is called, which follows a similar flow to

- `CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync` which reads the cookie and passes back a `ClaimsPrincipal`,
- this is assigned to `HttpContext.User`, making it accessible to all the other areas of the request pipeline, like authorization, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L54)

Comment: This still does not answer the question: "What exactly do we need to do to make this work"? :) In my case, I have IdentityServer in my solution, which already used in *HttpApiHost* layer by indicating `context.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")...`. I want to make use of *IdentityServer* via `signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync` or `signInManager.SignInAsync` in *AppService* layer and have similar error message regarding "Identity.Application"...

Comment: Well - I did answer the question, which was "Where does `Identity.Application` come from?" 

Regardless, without seeing more of your startup, it's difficult to say exactly - however, `AddAuthentication` by itself is probably not enough, since `AddIdentity`, which I reference above, calls `AddAuthentication` AND `AddCookie` and it's in `AddCookie` where the authentication scheme "Identity.Application" gets stood up.  Sounds like it is expecting this scheme, but it hasn't been setup yet.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Anyway, at last I've implemented the functionality I needed and now have a clearer understanding of how it should work :)