# ASP.NET Core 3 No Sign-In Manager Is Registered for the Scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I have been trying to incorporate Identity Server 4 into my ASP.NET Core 3 application and continually get the following error:

> No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme
>   'Identity.Application.

The registered sign-in schemes are: Cookies. Did you forget to call `AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Identity.Application",...)`? and I'm not sure what the error means.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521125/asp-net-core-2-2-signinmanager-no-sign-in-authentication-handler-is-registered) SO question, [this (Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1) MS .NET article, as well as several others, but none have helped.

My `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

    var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

    services
        .AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // , opt => opt.LoginPath = "/Identity"
        .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            opt.SaveToken = true;
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

    services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(opt =>
    {
        opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        opt.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<RbIdentityContext>();

    // == The original "AddIdentity" method automatically added all of the following
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483589/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-w/48598575/#answer-56551234
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // Identity services
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>, UserValidator<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>, PasswordValidator<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>, RoleValidator<IdentityRole>>();
    // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
    services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    // 
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}
```

My controller contains:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]UserModel model)
{
    var result = await _signInMgr.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false).ConfigureAwait(true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
        return Ok();
    else
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = ErrorHelper.SetControllerError("Invalid user name or password.") }));
}
```

The error occurs when executing `_signInMgr.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because `.AddIdentityCore()` doesn't configure the cookies for you. You'd need to call `.AddIdentity()` to have it set up automatically. Otherwise, you have to do it yourself.

```cs
        .AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
```

Edit:

To see what is happening inside the service collection extension methods called `AddIdentity()` check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v3.1.0/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) related to this code.