# Why is await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth", claimsPrincipal); throwing No sign-in authentication handlers are registered? (Razor Page model)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I'm trying to do a simple user authentication with the following code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();
            
            //verfiy the credential
            if(Credential.UserName == "admin" && Credential.Password == "password")
            {
                //Creating the security context
                var claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@mywebsite.com")
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCookieAuth");
                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth", claimsPrincipal);
                
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

await HttpContext.SignInAsync throws:

fail:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth",...)?
.
.
.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth",...)?

Comment: Are you using .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 6? Based on my search results only adding authentication is not enough and you also need to add the AddCookie. For more information, you could refer to this [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521125/asp-net-core-2-2-signinmanager-no-sign-in-authentication-handler-is-registered). I would suggest you provide more information about your project may help to narrow down the issue. [Helpful document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in program.cs class :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your startup.cs find public void ConfigureServices and make sure it looks like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
        });
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In program.cs add this snippet

```
`builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options => 
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
});`
```